# Apply format to multiple arrays in R

Tags: r, arrays, formatting

I am new to R and to stack overflow so apologies is this is not clear or I haven't included enough information. Many thanks!

I have three 3D arrays in R: Array_A, Array_B, and Array_C

All three arrays are displaying the values within them in scientific notation (i.e. 1.005e-01) instead of numeric (i.e. 0.1005). I have snooped around and worked out how to format an individual array as numeric using the code:

`format(Array_A, scientific=FALSE)`

Is there an easy way to apply this to all three arrays without using three lines of code (one for each array)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like the following will do what the question asks for. Untested, since there are no data sets.

```
Array_names <- ls(pattern = "^Array")
Arrays <- mget(Array_names)
Arrays <- lapply(Arrays, format, scientific = FALSE)
list2env(Arrays, envir = .GlobalEnv)

rm(Array_names, Arrays)    # final clean up
```